# Deploy a business network on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger

I use this tutorial to deploy a business network on a free bluemix cluster: https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/

I also deploy the REST Server and communicate via Web apps.

All went fine till yesterday. The REST Server was not accessible anymore.
I deleted everything on the cluster using the script delete_all available in the ibm-container-service repository.

I followed the install procedure using the create_all script. I could access the composer playground (port 31080) again but was not really able to deploy an online business network using the "profile" hlfv1. Now it asks at the bottom of the "deploy UI" for credentials.

I don't know what to fill in. I tried to use ID+Password. On this way I was able to deploy but I got access error by clicking on "connect now". I was able to start the REST server then but if i try to access it in the browser (port 31090), I get the feedback that I'm not authorized.

Any ideas?
And do you know which changes have been made in the last month, which could bring these troubles?

Thx

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial pointed to only covers playground when used with a Web Browser connection not a real fabric. When you deploy to a real fabric you have to provide an initial identity that you want bound to an initial participant in the business network. The initial participant will be of type `org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin` and given a name of the initial identity name you provide.

This dialog looks like this
[image: Credentials]

To get you started you should select the `ID and Secret` radio button. Then for Enrollment ID enter `admin` and for the Enrollment Secret enter `adminpw`.
This is the name and secret of the bootstrap identity that exists in the fabric-ca server that has been deployed as part of the scripts.
By providing this information that identity will be enrolled and it's public certificate will be bound to a NetworkAdmin participant which will be called `admin`. This identity `admin` will then have access to the business network as only identities that are bound to a participant in the business network can have any sort of access.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. I will try it in the next days and I will give you a feedback.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I forgot to answer. It worked fine. Thanks David!!